# How do I set AssemblyVersion with * for auto build number in MBUILD 15?

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-15

I still want to let my new csproj generate the version number for my library with the new msbuild. But how do I allow the old msbuild behavior of filling in a random build number with an asterix `*` placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to turn off rosyln deterministic builds `<Deterministic>False</Deterministic>`

Then you can use `*` safely in `<AssemblyVersion>` If want to get rid of compiler warnings, us `<VersionPrefix>` to set  `<AssemblyVersion>` and  `<FileVersion>` separately without duplication.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
...
    <VersionPrefix>1.11.31</VersionPrefix>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(VersionPrefix).*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>$(VersionPrefix)</FileVersion>
    <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
```